# Why does my .val() return undefined even though id is correct and the script is in the right place?

Tags: php, jquery, parsing

I'm trying to parse some data from generated HTML which displays objects from a database to jquery.

Here's how info within blocks is generated:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
<div class="item-info-div" style="padding: 5px;">
            //different fields output
            <a><?= $item->dailyRate ?> per day</a><br>
//then I generate a unique id using field name + id
            <input type='hidden' name='dailyRate' id='dailyRate<?=$item->id?>'
             value='<?=$item->dailyRate?>'>
//then I have a button that should parse the data to jquery
            <input type='submit' name='add_to_list' class='btn btn-warning my-2 add' 
            value='Add To list' id='<?=$item->id?>'>
</div>
```

Then in the file where I generate the blocks, I put the script right before the closing body  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".add",function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var dailyRate = $("#dailyRate"+id+"").val();

    console.log('I am the current value: ' + dailyRate);  
});
 }); 
</script>
```

The thing is when I look at the HTML source in a browser, both value and id for the field are generated properly. If I do the same concatenation in jquery ("#dailyRate"+id+""),  it does produce the same string as the one in the HTML source.
var Id is alerted just fine. Why does this .val statement return undefined when alerted/console.logged? What should I do to make it store the value of the hidden input?
I have tried changing the datatype for dailyRate in the database (let's say it's bigint), it still says undefined.

UPD: My bad, the problem was with the data. Instead of a serial ID in my project, we use generated ID which features spaces. Because of them, jquery couldn't point at the address (id) correctly. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680889/hasan-%c4%b0slamo%c4%9elu the problem was solved.
Solution I really needed: `id='dailyRate<?=str_replace(' ','',$vehicle->regNum)?>'`

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML and the JS code as [mcve]. We cannot guess what is wrong without having the real code. [If I were to just substitute with valuies it works](https://jsbin.com/vetasin/1/edit?html,console,output) but this is not necessarily representative of your real code.

Comment: I figured out that the problem was not inherently with the code but the data. In my project I don't use serial id as the primary key, it looks something like LG01 VXT and there are always spaces there. I guess that's why jquery didn't see the address of id. 
Do you know whether I should make another question about how to format the data in jquery and somehow delete this one?

Answer (score -2):

I wrote your code and it's perfectly worked. You should check your object or jquery call. You can find the working example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$item = new StdClass();
$item->id = 1;
$item->dailyRate = 5;
$items = array($item);

?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>

<div class="item-info-div" style="padding: 5px;">
            //different fields output
            <a><?= $item->dailyRate ?> per day</a><br>
//then I generate a unique id using field name + id
            <input type='hidden' name='dailyRate' id='dailyRate<?=$item->id?>'
             value='<?=$item->dailyRate?>'>
//then I have a button that should parse the data to jquery
            <input type='submit' name='add_to_list' class='btn btn-warning my-2 add' 
            value='Add To list' id='<?=$item->id?>'>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".add",function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var dailyRate = $("#dailyRate"+id+"").val();

    console.log('I am the current value: ' + dailyRate);  
});
 }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the log says there is a syntax error, I can't see whether the code works. I have recreated the HTML file and it says the same 
Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #dailyRate<?=$item->id?>",
  "filename": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js",
  "lineno": 2,
  "colno": 13633
}

Comment: you should save as .php file. for example, "index.php". just copy the code which I shared with you and create "index.php" file and serve via php -S localhost:8080 and then visit the http://localhost:8080 page and click the button. you cannot run php codes in .html file.

Comment: So, I actually figured it has to do with values that are being inputted. If you try to run this, it will say undefined. I suppose it's because of the space in id of input, do you have any idea on how to avoid it when parsing the data?
<input type='hidden' name='dailyRate' id='dailyRateLG01 VXT' value='235'>
<input type='submit' name='add_to_list' class='btn btn-warning my-2 add' value='Add To list' id='LG01 VXT'>

Comment: of course. if there is only space problem use this code :  id='dailyRate<?=str_replace(' ','',$item->id)?>' and for button id='<?=str_replace(' ','',$item->id)?>'

Comment: @HasanİSLAMOĞLU Edit the answer when you have the answer to the question, this answer isn't sufficient.